# How to fetch data (Step Count, Heart Rate, etc.) from Smartwatch like Noise and firebolt in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, noise, sony-smartwatch, heartrate

I want to get health related data from smartwatch like noise and firebolt and show it in UI in Flutter app which are connected by bluetooth.

I tried all the suggestions and all the GitHub source codes but they were not working.

Comment: Have you tried https://pub.dev/packages/health ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @esentis I checked the health plugin, but there was only setup for google fit and apple health, every answer on stack suggested flutter_blue plugin, but can't get the proper source code for it yet. still trying.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to fetch data from smartwatch unless the developer gives access to it.Maybe try developing a watchOS app ,using products that enables developer mode (eg:apple) to access the data from the watch itself. Thankyou:)